# Run a Python Script from a Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

My file name is 'corr.py' located in the Downloads folder and I'm running python 2.7 in terminal in the correct working directory. When I run the command 'python corr.py' I get the error message below. What should I do?

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/Daniel/Downloads'
>>> python corr.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python corr.py
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python3 corr.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python3 corr.py
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're in a Python interpreter already. First type `exit()` to get back to the terminal. (Or just open a new terminal tab/window.) Then use `python corr.py`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. The first line of code in my script is import pandas as pd. When I run the script, I get the message, "ImportError: No module named pandas." How do I fix that?